# Nestjs passport authentication with multiple strategies

Tags: nestjs

I have multiple authentication strategies, example for one of them:

```js
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'employee') {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    @Inject(appConfig.KEY)
    configService: ConfigType<typeof appConfig>,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: configService.EMPLOYEE_KEY,
    });
  }

  async validate({ phone }: JwtPayload) {
    const employee = await this.authService.authByRole(phone, Role.Employee);

    if (!employee) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('insufficient scope');
    }

    return employee;
  }
```

And some others mostly like this one. But because i throw unauthorized exception inside it, i cannot use multiple of them at the same route/controller. E.g.

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard(['employee', 'admin']))
```

The first one that crashes leading to error. How to solve that problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question. What do you wanna do exactly?

Comment: why do you need multiple on the same route? just make different login routes like `/login/employee` and `/login/admin`

Comment: Can you share the `AuthGuard`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@xxx_coder_noscope Your vision of the strategy is a bit wrong. The strategy here is a way how to get a special token, secret key, etc from a defined place(HTTP header, query, param, cookies, etc). The entity returned from the `validate()` method will be injected to request object as `user` property.

Later via creating an `EmployeeGuard` as `EmployeeGuard implements CanActivete` and overriding `canActivate()` method check user role by type and return boolean for allowing or decline access to endpoint